# Stripe form not working

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm working through [this example](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form) on stripe and the promised form interruption never happens. The form just submits normally and that's the end of it.

In my head I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Stripe.setPublishableKey('mytestkey');</script>
```

Then, here is my form:

```
<form action="/your-charge-code" method="POST" id="payment-form">
<span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>
<input type=hidden name=publication_id value="<?php echo $pub_id; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>
```

and the javascript is in a linked file:

```
$(function() {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.submit(function(event) {
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;
  });
});
```

When I submit, it just goes to the form action (I have not set anything for that yet).

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing an object to Stripe.card.createToken, as explained here:

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?#collecting-card-details

Also, make sure you have defined the stripeResponseHandler.

Comment: The [example](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form) included in the description by the OP does state: ` The first argument is the payment details. This can either be provided as individual members of a generic object, or by passing along a reference to the entire form.` but perhaps the main issue is that the response handler isn't being defined...

Comment: Thanks, but according to the instructions, this is already being handled in the javascript function at Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler) (it creates the object from the form inputs). Well, I tried it the way you are suggesting but the behavior is the same.

Comment: That was it @sam Onela. I was going step by step, but I guess I needed to do it all at once.